# Controller For SGS3 Mini

Tags: remote-control, game-controllers

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini and I would like to know if I can Play games trough a controller to make it more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Android supports USB controllers (using the standard USB *HID* profile) and Bluetooth controllers (again, if they use the standard Bluetooth HID profile). Wireless controllers that use a special wireless receiver probably won't work with Android (but they might if the wireless receiver acts as a USB HID device).

To use a USB controller with your phone, you need a USB-on-the-go adapter so you can plug the USB cable into the USB-on-the-go socket on your phone (i.e. the same socket you use to charge it).

In addition, the game needs to be written specifically to support game controllers. The description of the game on Google Play will probably mention controller support. It might have settings for the button layout (since not all controllers use the same layout), or it might be designed for one kind of controller in particular (such as Playstation controllers and clones).

There are even some Bluetooth game controllers designed specifically to work with smartphones, such as the Moga Pro. They have the conventional button layout, and often include their own app store selling compatible apps and games.